# Undefined method in migration while trying to massage data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 3. Here is my code:

```
class AddForAutocompleteInShops < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :shops, :for_autocomplete, :string
  end

  Shop.reset_column_information

  shops = Shop.all

  shops.each do |shop|
    shop.for_autocomplete = %(#{shop.name} #{shop.formatted_address})
    shop.save
  end

  def down
    remove_column :shops, :for_autocomplete
  end
end
```

Error message occurred:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `for_autocomplete=' for #<Shop:0x007fba66be7af8>
/Users/abc/Sites/test/db/migrate/20130219121256_add_for_autocomplete_in_shops.rb:11:in `block in <class:AddForAutocompleteInShops>'
/Users/abc/Sites/test/db/migrate/20130219121256_add_for_autocomplete_in_shops.rb:10:in `each'
/Users/abc/Sites/test/db/migrate/20130219121256_add_for_autocomplete_in_shops.rb:10:in `<class:AddForAutocompleteInShops>'
/Users/abc/Sites/test/db/migrate/20130219121256_add_for_autocomplete_in_shops.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What's wrong with my code? I tested in Rails console it works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be part of either the `up` or `down` methods - not in the middle of your migration class.

Answer (score 1):

```
    class AddForAutocompleteInShops < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def up

        add_column :shops, :for_autocomplete, :string

        Shop.reset_column_information

        shops = Shop.all

        shops.each do |shop|
          shop.for_autocomplete = %(#{shop.name} #{shop.formatted_address})
          shop.save
        end
      end



      def down
        remove_column :shops, :for_autocomplete
      end
    end

Try this.
```